# How to run a python script through VBA Excel macro?

Tags: python, pandas, vba, dataframe

I am trying to run a python script by running a macro on Excel VBA. Following is the Macro code:

```vb
Sub RunPython()    
    Dim objShell As Object
    Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

    Dim PythonExe As String
    PythonExe = """C:\Users\X\X\python3.exe""" 

    Dim PythonScript As String
    PythonScript = """C:\Users\Filename.py"""  

    objShell.Run PythonExe & " " & PythonScript

End Sub
```

The python script is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

def getExcel():
   df = pd.read_excel("Location where excel is saved")
   print(df)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   getExcel()
   input("Press any key to exit")
```

When I run the macro, the command line appears for a few seconds and then disappears. It does not run the code.

To debug, I tried to run a simple python script (which does not contain a pandas dataframe - then the macro code works perfectly and the script is also executed). But as soon as I write the code for a pandas df - It stops working.

P.S. Pandas is already saved and updated to the latest version on my system.

Please help!

Comment: When you execute python script out of Excel, does it run correctly?

Comment: If I execute it using the command line or jupyter notebook, it works properly.

Comment: Instead of `objShell.Run` try `Shell`. If the file you try to read `pd.read_excel("Location where excel is saved")` is already open in Excel for example this might be an issue. Try a more simple python script that just outputs `hello world` to see if it runs from VBA so you can figure out if the issue is in VBA or Python.

Comment: I tried to run a simple hello world program - That works absolutely fine!

Comment: Problem arises as soon as I use pandas functions in the code. Even if I don't use the pd.read_excel function and just normally create a simple dataframe - It stops working. Some issue with pandas, maybe?